# Код не выводит нужное

Tags: java

```
class pitaus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5;
        int res = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i >= 10 && i >= 1; i++) {
            res = res*i;
            System.out.println(a + " * " + i + " = " + res);
        }
    }
}
```

Почему код не выводит то, что в `System.out.println`?

Answer (score 2):

Это условие:

```
i >= 10 && i >= 1
```

Означает, что цикл будет продолжаться пока `i` не меньше 10 И не меньше 1. Т.к. `i` равно 1, цикл ни разу не выполняется.

Цикл от 1 до 10 пишется так:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
```